# How do I fix MBR on Windows XP? (no such partition after removing Linux)

Tags: windows-xp, grub, mbr

I need some basic help with fixing partitions.

I have installed Linux on a partition but then I had to reclaim the space.

I used **diskmgmt** to erase partition and then **easeus partition tool** - to resize exisitng one.

Generally after starting computer it says: *"Error no such partition. Grub rescue"*

## How to resolve it?

I have created Windows XP flash USB using **wintoflash** and it's kind of work... I can boot to the previous operating system, but I cannot go to repair / recovery console to proceed with fixboot / fixmbr instructions listed here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1014708

Some people were recommending - **PTDD** - but it is no longer available.

So I have access to my Windows XP, but only if bootable USB is in the slot... Would you recommend me some **fixmbr tool running on XP**?

**UPDATE:** Somehow I managed to get ptdd partition table doctor and solving the problem was as easy as right-click and "fix mbr" :)

Comment: It's best to add your solution as an answer and marked this question as solved.  And please tag it as a windows-xp question.

Comment: Will do it: Users with less than 100 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You may self-answer in 3 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead.

Comment: Boot from an XP install disk, load recovery console and then run "fixmbr" command....http://www.techrepublic.com/article/10-things-you-can-do-when-windows-xp-wont-boot/6031733

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me:

> Somehow I managed to get ptdd partition table doctor and solving the
>   problem was as easy as right-click and "fix mbr"

Note: PTDD is discontinued and you cannot download it from the official website.